# 0% form opacity without affecting controls (items) in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface, transparent-control

How can I do 0% form opacity without affecting controls (items)?

I found *[Changing form opactity without changing opacity of contained controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/178887/changing-form-opactity-without-changing-opacity-of-contained-controls)*, but there is no answer. What is the answer?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Changing form opactity without changing opacity of contained controls](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/178887/changing-form-opactity-without-changing-opacity-of-contained-controls)